# C# casting of derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

A noob question...

I've got two classes, a common(parent) one and a specialized(child)one :

```
public abstract class BaseTest
{
   public BaseTestSettings Settings{get;set;}
   public abstract void Run();
}

public class BaseTestSettings
{
   public double SettingsProp1{get;set;}
   public double SettingsProp1{get;set;}
}

public class SpecializaedTestSettings : BaseTestSettings
{
   public double SpecializaedTestSettingsPropA{get;set;}
   public double SpecializaedTestSettingsPropB{get;set;}
}

public class SpecializaedTest : BaseTest
{
   public SpecializaedTest()
   {
      this.Settings = new SpecializaedTestSettings();
   }

   public override void Run()
   {
      SpecializaedTestSettings settings = (SpecializaedTestSettings)this.Settings;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid casting in the overridden Run method in the specialized test ? I guess a solution would be to define a `Settings` property of type `SpecializedTestSettings` in the `SpecializedTest` class, but my goal is to avoid to this and declare those properties only once. I guess I can't ?

Comment: is using *Generics* an option?

Comment: You could possibly convert your `BaseTest` to a templated class that takes settings type as its type parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/512aeb7t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) :

```
public abstract class BaseTest<TSettings> where TSettings : BaseTestSettings
{
   public TSettings Settings{get;set;}
   public abstract void Run();
}

public class BaseTestSettings
{
   public double SettingsProp1{get;set;}
   public double SettingsProp1{get;set;}
}

public class SpecializaedTestSettings : BaseTestSettings
{
   public double SpecializaedTestSettingsPropA{get;set;}
   public double SpecializaedTestSettingsPropB{get;set;}
}

public class SpecializaedTest : BaseTest<SpecializaedTestSettings>
{
   public SpecializaedTest()
   {
      this.Settings = new SpecializaedTestSettings();
   }

   public override void Run()
   {
      SpecializaedTestSettings settings = this.Settings;
   }
}
```

If you need a non generic/covariant version you can write a covariant interface or a non generic base type.

Comment: Good solution, I considered it, but I've got more than one property like `Settings`, so I would have to use something like BaseTest<TSettings, TOtherClass1, TOtherClass2,...> not very elegant ?

Comment: Maybe you can aggregate TOtherClassN inside the TSettings type and keep only one generic parameter ?